# Matrix in python: transposing 2nd column into matrix row then populating with data in 3rd column

Tags: python, csv, matrix

New to python here (but have experience in R, SQL).
I tried googling this, however was unable to generate new ideas.
My main purpose is to generate a matrix using my csv data, but I'd like to transpose my 2nd column into a row for the matrix. I'd then like to populate that matrix with the data in my 3rd column, but wasn't able to get anywhere.

After a couple of days, I have come up with this code :

```
    import csv
    def readcsv(csvfile_name):
           with open(csvfile_name) as csvfile:
           file=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    #remove rubbish data in first few rows
           skiprows = int(input('Number of rows to skip? '))
                for i in range(skiprows):
                     _ = next(file)

    #change strings into integers/floats
                for z in file:
                     z[:2]=map(int, z[:2])
                     z[2:]=map(float, z[2:])
                     print(z[:2])
            return
```

This just cleans up my data, however what I'd like to do is to transpose the data into a matrix. The data I have is like this (imagine x,y,z,d and other letters are floats):

```
       1  1  x
       1  2  y
       1  3  z
       1  4  d
       .  .  .
       .  .  .
```

However, I'd like to turn this data into a matrix like this: i.e. I'd like to populate that matrix with data in the 3rd column (letters here just to make it easier to read for you guys) and convert the 2nd column into a row for the matrix. So in essence, the first and second columns of that CSV file are co-ordinates for the matrix.

```
          1  2  3  4  .  .
       1  x  y  z  d
       1  a  b  c  u 
       1  e  f  e  y
       .
       .
```

I tried learning numpy, however it appears like it requires my data to already be in a matrix form.

Comment: Where do `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. come from? Also, the result will not be a matrix, per se, since the first row has 1 less entry than the second... correct?

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be in numbers - just made it into letters to make it easier for you guys to read. The CSV file is massive - where there are heaps more rows compared to columns but after converting it into a matrix, it'd be square matrix after I transpose the 2nd column into the top matrix row and populating it with the 3rd column data. Sorry about my poor explanation, however hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Wait, are the first and second columns the coordinates for the matrix? For example, `[1, 1]` should be the cell `[0, 0]`, `[1, 2]` -> `[0, 1]`, `[2, 1] -> `[1, 0]` and so on? Could you give us a full example of what a full array looks like? (i.e. what values gave us the second and third row in your output?)

Comment: Yep! thats completely correct. First and second columns are the co-ordinates of the matrix. The values in the actual matrix are the data in the 3rd column in my CSV file.

Comment: I second `SCB`'s request for a little bit more data. I'm a little confused by your explanation, but what I suspect is that the line `1 4 d` is meant to be read as saying that the value `d` should be placed in the (1,4)-entry of the matrix (using 1 indexing). Is it true that the indices increase monotonically? That is, do we have `1 1` then `1 2` then `1 3` ... then `1 n` then `2 1` then `2 2`, and so on?

Comment: Yep! It's exactly that (i.e. value d in (1,4) entry and that value d corresponds to the 3rd column. My apologies if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use numpy you've got two options depending on how your data is stored.

1. If it is GUARANTEED that your keys increase consistently, e.g:

   ```
    THIS    NOT THIS
   ------   --------
   1 1 a    1 1 a
   1 2 b    1 3 b
   1 3 c    2 1 c
   1 4 d    3 1 d
   2 1 e    1 2 e
   2 2 f    1 4 f
   2 3 g    8 8 g
   2 4 h    2 2 h
   ```

   Then simply take all the values in the far right column and chuck them into a flat numpy array and reshape according to the maximum values in the left and middle column.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   m = np.array(right_column)
   # For the sake of example:
   #: array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.])
   m = m.reshape(max(left_column), max(middle_column))
   #: array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
   #:        [5., 6., 7., 8.]])
   ```
2. If it is not guaranteed, you could either sort it so that it is (probably easiest), OR create a zero array of the correct shape and cycle through each element.

   ```
   # Example data
   left_column =   [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
   middle_column = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4]
   right_column =  [1., 5., 3., 7., 2., 6., 4., 8.]

   import numpy as np
   m = np.zeros((max(left_column), max(middle_column)), dtype=np.float)
   for x, y, z in zip(left_column, middle_column, right_column):
       x -= 1 # Because the indicies are 1-based
       y -= 1 # Need to be 0-based
       m[x, y] = z

   print(m)
   #: array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
   #:        [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.]])
   ```

Comment: Sounds great! I should have mentioned that I wouldn't be able to take in 'all the values' in the far right column (or any columns) because there is literally around 500+ rows of data.

Comment: I was thinking of incoporating your code with some sort of "for" function, highlighting every elememnt in the 3rd column and then executing your code. Do you think numpy would be able to do that?

Comment: @dizzyLife you might want to take a look at [`fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) and using some [python generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to pull the numbers you want.

Comment: @dizzyLife oh and I wouldn't worry about the 'all the values' limitation. Literally around 500+ rows is comparatively tiny for a numpy array. With 64 bit floats, `(64 * 500) / 8 = 4000 Bytes = 4 kB`. Probably not worth worrying about till you're in the 100s of mB range.